# Suggestions for Fun Web Programming Projects at Home

Tags: apache, macos

Given Jeff Atwoods assertion that [All Programming is Web Programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001296.html), and having newly setup Apache on OSX with [dynamic DNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) on a home machine, what would the StackOverflow community suggest as fun programming projects to build on this, and what technologies to use?

Comment: Jeff Atwoods clearly has a limited understanding of the world.

Comment: Anyone can say anything from the hoof of their mouth.

Comment: Ultimately, this question isn't about what Jeff Atwood has or has not said.  It is about interesting web programming projects.

Comment: Jeff is full of hyperbole, but compared to Michael Braude he *absolutely* has a point. Apps dev is definitely diminishing, if not dying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I have always thought that it sounded fun to build a sort of media server that could stream my video and music collections and maybe even let me manage the files.  I also think some sort of family chalkboard like wiki would be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Put your goldfish online. Get a moveable camera, and/or a lego NXT robot and attach a camera to its arm. Create a web interface that lets you move the camera around and feed the goldfish etc. with your new robot while you're not at home. I've been sitting on that idea for months.

Comment: That sounds amazing depending on the activity level of one's goldfish.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you find fun. I can't tell you what you find fun. Think of something you want and make it.

-- Edit:

I'll list some things I find fun, perhaps for inspiration:

- Cryptography
- Fashion
- Maths
- Physics
- Bright Colours
- Inventing Things
- Guitar Hero
- Deploying Applications
- Arguing
- Spanish
- Music
- Debugging
- Investment

So the types of programs I write relate to these things; debugging visualiser, app to do deployments, websites describing my inventions, websites describing my clothing company, tools for manipulating images, tools for music generation, and starts of applications to manage financial portfolios.

Other such things.

Comment: Can you suggest any web development technologies worth using on OSX?

Comment: Well the server-language you choose has no bearing on the desktop you write it on.

Choose whatever language you have an interest in. I love C# so I'd do it in that. Kids these days tend to like Ruby and Python, so you could choose one of those.

If you were motivated enough you could write a webpage in masm. Use whatever you like and want to learn.

Comment: why would you even respond just to tell someone you have no suggestions?

Comment: Cause I was asked? And what is wrong with encouraging someone to work on something they find fun, as opposed to something that someone else finds fun or wants? I think that is important to re-inforce.

Comment: +1 this is good advice. Make something *you* would find useful. Once you get good at it, then you can look at making something for someone else!

Comment: "what would the StackOverflow community suggest as fun", and you reply "do what you think is fun." Brilliant and incisive..

Answer (score 0):

Create another Google. j/k. Well, you got be more specific. In what language, what interests others doesn't necessarily also excites you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something curiously Mac-ish to use as the technology, then you can get a lot of fun out of [WebObjects](http://developer.apple.com/tools/webobjects/index.html). You need to use Eclipse and WOLips as the dev environment these days. On the other hand, I think the [Cappuccino/Objective-J](http://cappuccino.org/) javascript framework is pretty cool, too.